# MSINotEnabled - Can't use KeyVault Reference in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to use a User Assign Managed Identity to retrieve access in KeyVault reference in Azure Function.

[image]

I'm following this doc [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#:~:text=you%20haven%27t%20already.-,Configure,-the%20app%20to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#:%7E:text=you%20haven%27t%20already.-,Configure,-the%20app%20to) to reference the keyvault in the application configuration.

I followed these steps:

1. Created User Assign Managed Identity.
2. Created a policy in Keyvault and gave permissions GET and LIST to User Assign Managed Identity.
3. Set the User Assign Managed Identity in Azure Function Identity
4. Set properties application setting like this:

- mysecureapp - @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykv.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/id)
- keyVaultReferenceIdentity - /subscriptions/subsid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mgid

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: So you followed this link: [Access vaults with a user-assigned identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-vaults-with-a-user-assigned-identity). Can you confirm you've set the `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` property with the resource id (not the client_id) ?

Comment: I'm using /subscriptions/subsid/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/mgid

Comment: is `mgid` the name of your managed identity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found that when the keyVaultReferenceIdentity property is created in the Function using the portal our IaC (App Settings), it doesn't recognize the User Assigned identity as the one to authenticate in KeyVault, but if you run the PATCH described in the following link using PowerShell, it works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-powershell#access-vaults-with-a-user-assigned-identity

it should be enough to the reference to KeyVault works

Answer (score 2):

I realized that in addition to setting the property **keyVaultReferenceIdentity** via app-setting, we need to change this property of the same name in the resource function. The default value is **SystemAssign** if you enable it. Unfortunately the MS documentation is unclear on this.

I found the property that can be used in the terraform documentation, follow the link: [https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#:~:text=key_vault_reference_identity_id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#:%7E:text=key_vault_reference_identity_id)

After setting this property to the value of User Assign Managed Identity this worked fine.

Comment: This is the same with web apps. Also if your using app configuration references this setting is required.

Answer (score 0):

wow !

I'm also searching the same topic for user identity and the same issue.
I just followed the marked answer , its worked and able to retrieve the value.

Thanks @ Magno Oliveira to bring this question to the community.

just need to run the CLI command in azure portal ! give resource group name and useridentity name and function app name to the below command

```
userAssignedIdentityResourceId=$(az identity show -g resourcegroupname -n manageidenityname --query id -o tsv)
appResourceId=$(az webapp show -g resourcegroupname -n functionappname --query id -o tsv)
az rest --method PATCH --uri "${appResourceId}?api-version=2021-01-01" --body "{'properties':{'keyVaultReferenceIdentity':'${userAssignedIdentityResourceId}'}}"
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you already done all the steps. But one thing you may missed i.e.,

- you have to ***enable*** the **system-assigned identity** for your application.

This error **MSINotEnabled** comes mostly during the absence of a managed Identity for your application, and it clearly says i.e., System assigned Managed identity.

Refer to this [medium article](https://medium.com/geekculture/troubleshooting-azure-key-vault-references-in-azure-function-apps-b228c1216f63) where we will find the troubleshooting steps had given along with all these kind of errors with resolutions were described.

Comment: I figured it would, but I don't understand how it needs me to enable the System Assign when I've already enabled the User Assign and I've also created the property keyVaultReferenceIdentity with the id of the managed identity

Comment: Even if I enable it, the error only changes to AccessToKeyVaultDenied because it doesn't have any policy with the Function System Assign in KeyVault, and it shouldn't, because I'm trying to use User Assign Managed Identity

Comment: Have you gone step ahead to refer the above medium article regarding why you got the error `AccessToKeyVaultDenied` after enabling the System Assigned Managed Identity because that article contains the solution for that error too!

Comment: Yes, I saw. But none of the information in the article helps me because my azure function and the keyvault are on the same subnet, leaving only the second reason that I don't have access because I didn't create an access policy for Systen Assign, but as I've informed before, need to use with User Assign, not System

Comment: Key vault reference works with user-assigned identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-vaults-with-a-user-assigned-identity. You don't need to enable system-assigned identity.

Comment: This is what the documentation says, but in practice it's not working.